# wrong screen resolution Ubuntu Studio 21.04

Tags: xorg, display, display-resolution

Ubuntu Studio 21.04 uses KDE Plasma 5.21. It does not recognize the native resolution, 3840x2160, of my Dell P2415Q monitor. Other Linux distro's do. Ubuntu Studio shows 2560x1440 as highest resolution. This is both with XOrg as with Wayland on a PC with Intel i3-8100 UHD630 graphics embedded.
I tried cvt and xrandr to add the following to /etc/X11/xorg.conf (which did not exist in that location):
`Section "Monitor" Identifier "DP-1" Modeline "3840x2160_60.00"  712.75  3840 4160 4576 5312  2160 2163 2168 2237 -hsync +vsync Option "PreferredMode" "3840x2160_60.00" EndSection`

But that does not have any effect. Is this a known issue? Is there a solution?
Thanks.

Comment: What other distros you tried that do recognize the native resolution?

Comment: Linux Mint, KDE Manjaro, MX Linux, all recent / current releases

Comment: That list makes no sense. Manjaro is a rolling release so it almost always has an newer kernel than Ubuntu but the others either lag behind or are au pair with Ubuntu. But if the current Mint works then Ubuntu Studio 20.04 should work the same.